# Auto Create Appointment based on Email

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm looking to try and have outlook automatically create an appointment based on the Subject line of an incoming email. For instance if I receive an email with the subject line "Demo Downloaded" I want it to create an appointment for this email that shows the body of the message as the "Note" on the Appointment. Also, I want the appointment TIME to be 2 hours after the date of the email was sent to me. So if I received the email at 1pm eastern i want the appointment to be automatically set for 3pm eastern.

I know I need to use VBA and have outlook run a script, which I know how to do all of this. However all I currently know right now is how to manually create an appointment based off the selected email, not the email that has been received. Plus I dont know how to have it automatically set the time or anything fancy like that...

This is currently all I have...

```
Sub CreateTask(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim objTask As Outlook.TaskItem
    Set objTask = Application.CreateItem(olTaskItem)
With objTask
    .Subject = Item.Subject
    .StartDate = Item.ReceivedTime
    .Body = Item.Body
    .Save
End With
    Set objTask = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your edited version ...

The mailitem is known from Sub CreateTask(**msg As MailItem**)

Try replacing

```
Sub CreateTask(msg As MailItem)
    Dim app As New Outlook.Application
    Dim item As Object
    Set item = GetCurrentItem()
    If item.Class <> olMail Then Exit Sub

    Dim email As MailItem

    Set email = item

    Dim meetingRequest As AppointmentItem

    Set meetingRequest = app.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
```

with

```
Sub CreateTask(msg As MailItem) 
    Dim meetingRequest As AppointmentItem
    Set meetingRequest = Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
```

Replace email with msg everywhere except in .SenderEmailAddress

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out after playing around with the code and reading up on a few other things. This is what I came up with.

```
Sub CreateTask(msg As MailItem)
    Dim app As New Outlook.Application
    Dim item As Object
    Set item = GetCurrentItem()
    If item.Class <> olMail Then Exit Sub

    Dim email As MailItem

    Set email = item

    Dim meetingRequest As AppointmentItem

    Set meetingRequest = app.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

    meetingRequest.Categories = email.Categories
    meetingRequest.Body = email.Body
    meetingRequest.Subject = email.Subject
    meetingRequest.Start = Date & " " & DateAdd("h", 3, Time)

    Dim attachment As attachment
    For Each attachment In email.Attachments
        CopyAttachment attachment, meetingRequest.Attachments
    Next attachment

    Dim recipient As recipient

    Set recipient = meetingRequest.Recipients.Add(email.SenderEmailAddress)
    recipient.Resolve

    For Each recipient In email.Recipients
        RecipientToParticipant recipient, meetingRequest.Recipients
    Next recipient

    Dim inspector As inspector

    Set inspector = meetingRequest.GetInspector

    meetingRequest.Save
    meetingRequest.Send

End Sub
```

However I have noticed that sometimes I get an error saying that this script can't be loaded. Does anyone know a better method or something I might be missing?

Comment: What is the exact error message and under what circumstances does it appear? BTW, I don't know if you know, but you can drag and drop an email onto the Calender button to create a related Appointment.